# Application Dispose in Global.asax

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, azure

Could anybody explain when Application Dispose from Global.asax is fired?

I would glad to see all possible reasons of it, because my application disposes by unknown reason.

FYI:

1. I **disabled** default (every 29 hours) **periodic application recycle** and set up it to specific time (3:00 AM).
2. I **set to zero** **Idle Time-out** (if site is unused for (by default) 20 minutes).

But I still get random application disposes (see it in the application's logs), which interrupt correct logic of the system.
Besides, one disposal is followed by several others which fire quite often with ~30 seconds interval.

I host my application on Azure Cloud Service with BizSpark subscription.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a rather Abstract question in nature I say that only because we can not see any of the code as well as all objects that you are using within your code.. perhaps you have some of your code wrapped in a `using` and it's disposing of some objects when or where you least expect it.. have you actually tried adding some Logging in all possible areas in the code and then eliminate them one by one through process of elimination.?

Comment: [Why is the IIS default app pool recycle set to 1740 minutes (29 hours)?](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes).

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I wrote that I disabled periodic app pool recycle.

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich It was only a comment for other readers in case they wondered how/why.

Comment: Did you disable the Idle Time-out for the app pool?

Comment: @RossBush, yes I did and actually it's mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: it's probably old but, how did you fixed it ?
I was in similar situation